# Testing if field is NONE with tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm trying to learn Python via tweepy. The simple bots are pretty simple.

I created one to search for words, but I want to know the city the tweets are coming from.

As a test, I have this bit of code:

```
if ' trump ' in status.text.lower():
    print status.coordinates 
    print ('geo'), status.geo
    print status.text
```

But I see that coordinates and geo are all **None**.

How can I test to see if the value is none, and eliminate from seeing these results?

Comment: You can test to see if the value is none with, err, `if value is None:`.

Comment: I've added the following:          
        if status.coordinates != "None"
                    print status.coordinates     but it's showing a syntax error. I've tried ' and ", but both won't work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You're missing a colon. Also you should use identity (`is`/`is not`) not equality (`==`/`!=`) for comparison to `None`, as it's a singleton.

Comment: It's always the colon. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you two possible way:

1. You can add a condition in your if statement as follow:

   ```
   if 'trump' in status.text.lower() and status.coordinates is not None:
   ```

   None is not a string so this is the reason because your code (`if status.coordinates != "None"`) raises a SyntaxError.
2. Don't change or add anything in if condition and print the value only if it is not None. 
   A possible way to do that is the following:

   ```
   if status.coordinates is not None:
       print status.coordinates
   ```

   or

   ```
   if status.coordinates:
       print status.coordinates
   ```

   and the complete script:

   ```
   if 'trump' in status.text.lower():
       if status.coordinates is not None:
           print status.coordinates
       if status.geo is not None:
           print ('geo'), status.geo
       print status.text
   ```

Comment: That works. Now I need to clear up the whole "  File "again2.py", line 24, in on_status
    writer.writerow([status.geo, status.coordinates, status.text])
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2026' in position 118: ordinal not in range(128)" issue.

Comment: Glad to help you! Anyway, I don't understand well the error in your comment, I suggest you to open another question with more details. If my answer has solved your first problem, please mark it, in order to be useful to other users with the same issue. Thanks